# Difference between tags language-exchange and tandem-learning?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We currently have two tags for — probably — the same thing:

The older tag [tandem-learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tandem-learning) is currently defined as follows:

> A language learning process involving mutual language exchange in which both partners are fluent in the language the other partner wants to learn.

The newer tag [language-exchange](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-exchange) is defined as:

> Questions related to learning a language by regularly communicating with a native (or near-native) speaker of your target language, whom you help learning your native language. Also known as tandem learning.

Should we merge the definitions and make one tag a synonym of the other?

Comment: Good find! As Hatchet mentioned, language exchange is the more used term, so it's best to make tandem learning a synonym of language exchange.

Comment: Apparently, this has been done now: [tag:tandem-learning] is now marked as a synonym for [tag:language-exchange].

Answer (score 3):

Since [language-exchange](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-exchange) is the more widely known term (try Googling each term), it should take precedence.

Comment: @Flimzy Wikipedia has an article on [tandem language learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_language_learning) and one on [language exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_exchange). The latter says that, "Language exchange is sometimes called Tandem language learning.". And funnily enough, only the latter links to the German article [Tandem (Sprachlernmethode)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_(Sprachlernmethode)). So is one of these the "technical term"?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe *shrug* As the change has already been made, I don't think there's any reason to change, regardless of which term is more "technical".